# How to create new SQL Server login and assign permission to access database to it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create an vb.net console application which will access our existing SQL Server database, but the problem is that the provider didn't give us login name and password to access the database.

So is there any way by which can I create a new login with password and assign them full permission or read permission to access the database ? I have full access to the system on which the SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed.

Comment: You have full access to the system AND you are a sysadmin on the SQL Server instance?

Comment: I don't have access to the SQL SERVER ,I meant I have access only to the physical computer system on which SQL SERVER is installed not to the SQL SERVER. Sorry for ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few assumptions made to this:

1) The SQL Server is set up to allow mixed authentication

2) The SQL Server is allowed to use TCP/IP or Named Pipes for logins

3) The account you say has "full access" to the system ALSO has sysadmin (aka full access) on the SQL server instance or at least permissions to do user maintenance.

Assuming all those then login to the SQL server and run something like below

```
CREATE LOGIN [app_usr] WITH PASSWORD=N'password', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[databaseName], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

USE [databaseName]
GO
CREATE USER [app_usr] FOR LOGIN [app_usr]
GO

/**** You can choose to only run the following statements that you want***/
-- The following gives the user the ability to read all tables in the db
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'app_usr'
GO

-- The following gives the user the ability to write to all tables in the db
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'app_usr'
GO

-- The following gives the user the ability to do anything in the db
USE [master]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'app_usr'
GO
```

Additional default roles and a better description can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles) or make your own or whatever - at this point the user is created and you should be able to access it through your application

Comment: I don't have access to the SQL SERVER ,I meant I have access only to the physical computer system on which SQL SERVER is installed not to the SQL SERVER. Sorry for ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have full access to the system on which the SQL Server 2008 R2 is
>   installed.

If you are `local Windows admin`, you can restart SQL Server in `single user` mode and you'll be `sysadmin` at that moment:

[Start SQL Server in Single-User Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236(v=sql.110).aspx)

There is another solution for `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

As previuosly said, you should be Windows admin on this pc.

You can access SQL Server under `LocalSystem` account using this program: [PsExec v2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Just run ir with `-s`   i.e. Run the remote process in the System account.

This way you can connect to SQL Server without restarting it at all.